# C++で日本語文字列を切り取りたい

Tags: c++, 日本語

C++11を用いて日本語の文字列の入力を受け取り、それ各文字ごとに切り抜いて数を数えるプログラムを作成しているのですが、日本語を扱ったのは始めてなので知見が足りません、できればstringにrange_based_forを書けたときのようにスラスラ取りたいです。

Comment: 使用している用語が曖昧すぎるかもしれません。1.対象とする「文字コード」を明示したほうが良いでしょう。2.string型とはstd::stringか、又はその他ものかも述べた方が良いと考えられます。3.「切り抜く」とは具体的にどのような操作かも必要です。rangebased forからは想像できませんでした。

Comment: とりあえず `std::u32string` ならいけそうですが…そういう話ではないかもしれませんね。質問が不明確です。

Comment: 通常の英文が格納されている文字列にchar型のrange_based_forをかけると,英字一つ一つが出てくると思います.それと同じように日本語一文字一文字を扱うような方法はないのかなあと言う質問ですね...

Comment: ２年近く経ってから質問文を編集する理由がよくわかりません。既に回答が付いていますが、回答に不足があるのであれば「答えて欲しいこと」を尋ねてください。

Answer (score 2):

[`std::string` / `std::wstring` / `std::u16string` / `std::u32string`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string.html) が用意されていますが、それぞれは対応する文字型（`char`など）を扱うとしか定められていません。例えば、C標準ライブラリには`stricmp`のような大文字小文字を区別しない比較が存在しますが、C++ stringにはこのような機能すらありません。
全てはライブラリ利用者に任せられているため、マルチバイト文字になるのであればその管理もライブラリ利用者の責任です。`std::u16string`を使用することでUTF-16を扱うことができますが、その場合でも[サロゲートペア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%9A%E3%82%A2)の管理は利用者の責任ですし、`std::u32string`でUTF-32としたとしてもやはり[異体字セレクタ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%95%B0%E4%BD%93%E5%AD%97%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF)などを考慮するとやはり１文字に収まることはありません。

結局のところ、何をもって「１文字」とみなすかは利用者次第であり、それに応じた処理を記述しすることになります。

Comment: 日本語を扱うのが始めてという事なので、単純に charとして扱うだけで良いのでは? と推測。　確かに異字体やら、サロゲートなど色々とありますが、これは日本語固有でなく、通常の日本語処理では考慮されない事も多いと思います。まずはどこまで丁寧に(正確に) 日本語を扱うかの検討が先と言う気がします。

Answer (score -1):

C/C++言語規格上はリテラルを除けば「文字列」という概念は無いに等しく
「文字コードを意味する型」の「配列」しかありません。
また、ANSI(Shift-JIS)(別名:MBCS)系コードと、Unicode系コードで扱いが異なります。

```
char     Nihongo_A[7] =  "日本語"; // char配列に日本語を入れてみた(Shif-JISコードの場合)
wchar_t  Nihongo_W[4] = L"日本語"; // ワイド文字の配列にUnicodeの日本語を入れてみた(UTF-16等の場合)
```

どちらも日本語を扱ってますが「１文字の概念」が文字コードによって異なるので、上記のように配列に必要な要素数が異なるわけですね。
例外を除けばwchar_t型は１文字を意味しますので配列インデックスを指定して１文字を判定できます。

```
if( Nihongo_W[1]==L'本'){
  // '本'でした
}
```

もちろん基本型の配列には Range-based for は使えますし、

```
for( wchar_t & jc : Nihongo_W){// 
  jc = L'あ';//全部'あ'にする
}
```

または、その機能を持っているより高度な「文字列クラス」もあるのでそれを使用すれば良いわけですね。

Comment: 皆様ご回答ありがとうございます！結局この問題はC/C++ではなくRubyを使用することによって解決しました。wchar_tの配列にする発想は思いつきませんでした。とても勉強になりました。